# How do I add a site to an existing LastPass password from that site?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, password-management, lastpass

I'm in the middle of switching password managers (from KeePass to LastPass), and I'm running into an issue with LastPass. I've manually moved all my passwords into my LastPass vault, but did not include URLs when creating the passwords. I now have a couple dozen username/password pairs with no associated URLs, and I'm not seeing an easy way to use the passwords I've entered in the normal username/password fields.

For example, I've put my Facebook username and password into LastPass under the name "Facebook", with no attached site: [image: lastpass]

When I go to Facebook and tap the LastPass icon in the credential fields, the password list appears, but is empty:
[image: facebook]

Entering "Facebook" into the filter field doesn't make the password appear. I can find the Facebook credentials in my LastPass extension, but I can't see a way to automatically enter these credentials into the username/password field, or to add the Facebook URL to the password without manually doing so.

Is there an automatic way to associate a password with a website, or will I have to enter all of my passwords or URLs manually to have them associated correctly? Clearly I should have attached URLs to these passwords in the first place, but now that I haven't, is there an easy way to make this work for me without manually adding every URL?

I'm using the LastPass extension on Firefox 67.0.

Comment: You went about the migration the incorrect way.  You should have while logged into LastPass, logged into each website, now you will have to figure out what website is for each “site”.   The name of the site, URL, username, and password are default fields for every site added.  If you don’t see a url field it’s unlikely you added sites but used some other feature.  Since this certainly is with the web application itself and not an add-on I have voted to migrate this question to web applications.  Encourage you to clarify the question with an example so we can see what you see.

Comment: I've added screenshots showing what I'm talking about. The issue, if I'm not explaining it well enough, is that in the second screenshot, there's no obvious way to say "use this password on this site", with a list of my Vaulted passwords.

Comment: @DuckTapeAI - You need to provide a URL in the URL field.  LastPass fills in fields based on the URL.  If you were to type your password and username on Facebook LastPass would ask if you wanted to save the site.  I suggest you do that so you better understand how LastPass works.

Comment: No.... you're going to need to link each password with a site manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this automatically from the page. You'll need to edit each password entry and add the URL to match manually.

It maybe easier to simply delete all the passwords from the vault and instead use the import function, which will import from Keepass, keeping the urls with the username/password pairs.

Comment: You could also use the import function which supports KeePass.  Although that would at this point result in duplicate entries.

Comment: Wasn't sure that was an option, thanks, I'll update my answer suggesting that should of been done in the first place.